# SQL Server 2008 Table Structure with Guid Performance Considerations

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, primary-key, guid

I'm actually in a dilemma right now with regards to whether or not to use Guid.

I have a non-transactional table called Posts with a bigint as PK.

As far as I understand, using Guid as PK would hamper query performance. However, in order to make query string truly unique, I decided to add a column called `specialID` with `Guid default value newid()`. This would make all my query strings truly unique since all I need to do is to execute the following query:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM Posts p 
 WHERE p.specialID = '[query-string]'; // For single record retrieval
```

As for Joins, bigint PK will come into play as follows:

```
SELECT p.id, p.specialID, ul.name as Writer 
  FROM Posts p 
  JOIN Users ul ON ul.id = p.writer;
```

My colleague, however, disagreed and said that it would still hamper query performance. Why? And should I continue this way? A truly unique query string isn't necessary, but would be preferred. If it would indeed hamper performance, how can we go about having a truly unique query string?

Comment: The more narrow the data type, the better the performance.  INT instead of BIGINT, etc.  Do you have the data to justify the BIGINT need?  I'd need to know more about why you need to use GUID, because performance doesn't matter if the design requires it.

Comment: Hello OMG Ponies, [edit, seems like Enter would just submit] I use bigint instead of int because I anticipate records to grow overtime, it's going to be huge. The reason for Guid is like stated, I want it as a truly unique query string. For example, if I were to access Posts with id 100, instead of Post.aspx?id=100, I can do Post.aspx?id=[Guid]

Comment: Until you have the data, you can use INT.  "truly unique query string" - your example is a primary key, which is no requirement to use a GUID when IDENTITY provides the same functionality at a fraction of the overhead.  Using a GUID as a GET parameter is also a more likely SQL injection attack vector than an numeric value.  Being longer, it's also a concern for the URL length.

Comment: Using a GUID as the **clustering key** in SQL Server (the key by which the data is physically sorted) is a horribly bad choice due to fragmentation and other performance issues. Having a GUID column otherwise isn't nearly as bad. So I'd say keep on going, put an index on it (make it a UNIQUE index) and keep an eye on the performance - but I wouldn't expect any significant/measurable negative impact

Comment: As for "running out of `INT` identity values": if you use an `INT IDENTITY` starting at 1, and you insert a row every second, every day, all year long, you need **66.5 years** before you hit the 2 billion limit ....

Comment: @OMGPonies - Thanks. That's precisely what I'm doing, using GUID as a GET parameter. As for SQL Injection, it is highly unlikely to happen as I'd first parse the GET parameter to GUID on .NET side, failing which an error message would be displayed. Also, since I am using Entity Framework as my ORM, SQL Injection can be eliminated entirely.

Comment: @marc_s Thanks for your reply. I don't intend to use GUID as a clustering key (highly unlikely). Think of me storing GUID as storing string, it's still GUID but treated as string, like any other varchar columns. I picked GUID is because it creates a string unique enough whereby every Post made by my user would be distinctively different (int / bigint achieve this too, but it's too obvious to be passed as GET parameter). Also, I understand about INT vs BIGINT, cheers for the advice :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It shouldn't significantly hamper SELECT queries, especially not if you properly index the column.  It can potentially affect Inserts, but that's less of an issue if the GUID isn't part of a clustered index.  It can also affect storage requirements, depending on how much data you're going to store since it's (obviously) a lot bigger.

A detailed discussion is Here:  http://www.sql-server-performance.com/2005/guid-performance/  although that is for 2005, I believe all the points are still valid.

** EDIT:  simple index example **
A 'covering index' just means you have an index which includes the column in question.  A clustered index means that the records are actually stored in the order that the index says, a nonclustered index means that the index holds a pointer to the stored location. Consider the difference like a dictionary vs. a book's index. A  dictionary is sorted in word order, and stores all its data in that order (clustered) while an index is sorted in word order, but has a pointer to page numbers which aren't in the same order (nonclustered).

So to make an index for your column, you would do:

```
CREATE INDEX idx_posts_specialId
    ON Posts (specialID); 
GO
```

Default is nonclustered, but you can add the 'nonclustered' keyword if you want to be explicit.

Comment: Hello Paul, thanks for your reply. However, the scenario mentioned in the article is based on Guid being a PK while in my case, Guid isn't a PK. I'm interested to know more about Guid's performance when it is NOT a PK. Storage is one disadvantage, but it is pretty much like any other varchar columns, just one more wouldn't hurt.

Comment: Yes, I understand that, I covered that part of things in the first paragraph of my response.  The article was to provide more detailed background.  In short, a guid isn't significantly worse on the Select than a integer is (so long as you have a covering index), and only suffers on inserts when the GUID column is part of a clustered index (as a PK usually is).

Comment: Thanks Paul. What is a covering index by the way? I'm quite noobish at SQL. I'm pretty much an ORM guy.

Comment: Nevermind, I did a search. But if you'd like to show how it can be achieved, it'll be even better. Thanks so much Paul.

Comment: Thanks Paul. Your answer is greatly appreciated.